# RX, retry and allow to handle exception

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable

I'm trying to wrap my head around RX but somewhere my brain explodes :)

What I'm trying to do is invoke a WCF method in an async way through RX.
Nothing special here, but when the WCF method throws an error I want to recreate the channel and give it another go (max 3 times).

What I have so far is:

```
var _sc = new Service.Service1Client();
var _observableFunc = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<int, string>(_sc.BeginGetData, _sc.EndGetData);
var _observable = _observableFunc(666);

var _defered = Observable.Defer(() => _observable);

// Here something should be done, but don't know what...

using (_retryable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Async ==> '{0}'", x),
                            ex => Console.WriteLine("Oops ==> {0}", ex.Message)))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I played around with `Catch<TSource, TException>`, which allowed me to trap the exception and continue with the same observable, hence giving me what I wanted.
Only problem is that it runs forever, meaning if I keep on throwing exceptions the thing never stops!

Comment: See if the Observable.Retry helps. Also, if you're just getting started with RX and your brain doesn't hurt, you're doing it wrong ;-)

Comment: Prolly right about my brain, but it's hurting less than yesterday :)

I discovered the Retry already but the problem was that my "hot" observable remained "hot, I didn't got the point of the Defer syntax completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
var retryable = Observable.Defer(() => _observableFunc(666).Retry(3));
```

The `Retry` extension method "Repeats the source observable sequence the specified number of times or until it successfully terminates."

Also, don't do this:

```
var _observable = _observableFunc(666);
var _defered = Observable.Defer(() => _observable);
```

There's no point deferring the observable after you've kicked it off.

You should do this instead:

```
var _defered = Observable.Defer(() => _observableFunc(666));
```

Then you're only one step away from my suggested solution at the top.

Comment: Yep, I found it out yesterday and was like "ahhhh, now that makes sense". Was about to post what I had done wrong, but your answer explains it all.

Thnx anyways!!!